# whoosh search after database migration

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, flask, whoosh

I migrated my database from sqlite3 to postgresql with the following three steps

1. I create a sqlite dump file with

   sqlite3 app.db .dump > app_dump.sql
2. I create a postgresql database and initialized it with my models.py file as

   python manage.py db init

where manage.py is

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://appuser:777@localhost/app_db' 
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

3. I used only the insert lines in the dump file to populate the new database.

This worked well, however I do want to have a whoosh search in my User table.

My models.py looks like this

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    enable_search = False
else:
    enable_search = True
    import flask.ext.whooshalchemy as whooshalchemy

class User(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['username','id'] 

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True)

if enable_search:
    whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, User)
```

However, the search does not seem to work at all. I fear that the table has not been properly indexed? Anybody know how I can fix this?
thanks
carl

EDIT:
Solved it... have a look at 
https://gist.github.com/davb5/21fbffd7a7990f5e066c

Comment: `python manage.py db init` only create the `migrations` folder and some basic scripts, not do the real work.

Comment: And I guess that you may add new data to the database using `SQLAlchemy`.

Answer (score 1):

By default flask_whooshalchemy indexes a record when the sqlalchemy session commits. So if you want to index all non-indexed-data you can try my fork which is called [flask_whooshalchemyplus](https://github.com/Revolution1/Flask-WhooshAlchemyPlus)  see the manually indexing introduction.